# Data Studio Community Connector: How to change Data freshness interval

Tags: looker-studio

My custom Google Data Studio Community Connector reads "Data freshness: 12 hours" when configuring the Data Source in [Google Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com/). How do I influence the data freshness interval displayed and / or the messaging displayed when this is selected? The "learn more" [link](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020039) furnished by Google Data Studios doesn't address how to manipulate this value.

Answer (score 0):

On the panel on the right, select the *Data* tab, then click the pencil next to your Data Source, and a panel should slide up from the bottom.  At the top of this panel, you'll see "Data Freshness" which you can set to increments small as 15 minutes.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I've updated the question to be more specific. Apologies for not calling this out in the first place. I'm interested in updating the Data Freshness for a custom community connector. I followed the steps that you describe and the "Data Freshness" option doesn't seem to be available for a custom community connector.

Answer (score 0):

Community connectors always set "Data freshness" to 12 hours.

This is by design, please upvote the feature to change it:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/161156075